# Form data doesn't fill in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, form-data

I have a very basic project with next js in this project i have a simple form . when I submit this form i put my data in form Data with append method and after that when i log my form data in console it is an empty object and i'm so wondering why this is happened
this is my code

```js
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import {useState} from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: '',
        mobile: ''
    });
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setInputs(prev => {
            const cloneState = {...prev};
            cloneState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
            return cloneState;
        });
    }

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', inputs.name);
        formData.append('mobile', inputs.mobile);
        console.log(formData, 'FD');
    }
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <form>
                <input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} name='name'/>
                <input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} name='mobile'/>
                <button type='submit' onClick={clickHandler}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

thanks all of you in advanced

Comment: its working. The formData are populating. what not working exactly for u?

Comment: i receive an empty object in my console :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you log the formData object in console it will log the formData object. You need to call the 'get' method to get the values. If you want to get a json from  a formData object use the code below.

```
console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))
```

Comment: that's how we need to access the `formData`

Comment: thanks alot and if i want POST with content-type : multipart-form using fetch is this approach ok? @Prana

Comment: @AliEhyaie you can directly send the formData object in the request body. No need to convert it to js object.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the instance of `FormData` is not a plain JS object, but its a `FormData` object, hence you can't log it directly into console.

To check its entries, you can do:

```
[...formData.entries()].forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem related to getting values from formData.
You can get data from formData using get() method, or getAll() in order to get all values with the same name inside the array.
For getting all values from formData you can use for...of loop like this one.

```
for (let value of formData.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks)